# Angular decorator/extending UI Bootstrap Datepicker directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to extend the angular ui bootstrap date picker directive. My aim is to be able to override the positioning of the datepickerdirective. The positioning happens on a $watch event inside of the uibDatepickerPopupController which is bound to the uibDatepickerPopup directive. I'm following the guide here to decorate a directive that has a mapped controller here. http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/09/experiment-decorating-directives/

I'm getting the following error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

So far I have the following:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="popup.opened" />
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
</span>
```

and a basic angular controller

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ui.bootstrap"]);

    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) { 
       $scope.dt = new Date();

       $scope.open = function() {
          $scope.popup.opened = true;
       };

       $scope.popup = {
          opened: false
       };
    });
```

Here is my attempt to override the behavior

```
var uibModel = angular.module("ui.bootstrap");
uibModel.config(function($provide) {
   $provide.decorator('uibDatepickerPopupDirective', function($delegate, $controller) {
      var directive = $delegate[0];

      var controllerName = directive.controller;

      directive.controller = function($scope, $element, $attrs, $compile, $parse, $document, $rootScope, $uibPosition, dateFilter, uibDateParser, uibDatepickerPopupConfig, $timeout, uibDatepickerConfig) {
         var controller = $controller(controllerName, {
            $scope: $scope,
            $element: $element,
            $attrs: $attrs,
            $compile: $compile,
            $parse: $parse,
            $document: $document,
            $rootScope: $rootScope,
            $uibPosition: $uibPosition,
            dateFilter: dateFilter,
            uibDateParser: uibDateParser,
            uibDatepickerPopupConfig: uibDatepickerPopupConfig,
            $timeout: $timeout,
            uibDatepickerConfig: uibDatepickerConfig
         });

         $scope.position.top = 0;

         return controller;
      };
   });
});
```

http://codepen.io/mantisimo/pen/OMeExN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be other issues, but the one that I see is that you need to return directive from your decorator function because Angular needs to know which element in the $delegate array your are decorating (yes, there could be multiple)

```
var uibModel = angular.module("ui.bootstrap");
uibModel.config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('uibDatepickerPopupDirective', function($delegate, $controller) {
      var directive = $delegate[0];

      var controllerName = directive.controller;

      directive.controller = function($scope, $element, $attrs, $compile, $parse, $document, $rootScope, $uibPosition, dateFilter, uibDateParser, uibDatepickerPopupConfig, $timeout, uibDatepickerConfig) {
         var controller = $controller(controllerName, {
            $scope: $scope,
            $element: $element,
            $attrs: $attrs,
            $compile: $compile,
            $parse: $parse,
            $document: $document,
            $rootScope: $rootScope,
            $uibPosition: $uibPosition,
            dateFilter: dateFilter,
            uibDateParser: uibDateParser,
            uibDatepickerPopupConfig: uibDatepickerPopupConfig,
            $timeout: $timeout,
            uibDatepickerConfig: uibDatepickerConfig
         });

         $scope.position.top = 0;

         return controller;
      };

      return directive;

   });
});
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you, cant believe I missed that!! 
Thanks again :)